# Display Driver Crashes On Second Run Of App

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, webcam

Basically, I have a super simple metro app I'm working on at the moment. All it does at the moment is display a webcam video stream.  All the relevant current code is below (capture is a CaptureElement defined in XAML, and mediaCapture is of type MediaCapture). The code works perfectly the first time I run the program in debug local system mode from VS 2012. I then close the app by dragging it from the top. However, the next time I go to run the program, my display driver crashes - from the Windows Event Viewer: "Display driver igfx stopped responding and has successfully recovered.". I'm new to doing any development in C#, so I'm not really sure where to begin looking for what's causing this. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
    private async void init()
    {
        mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
        MediaCaptureInitializationSettings mc = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
        mc.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video;
        await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(mc);
        capture.Source = mediaCapture;
        await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
    }
```

Note: init() is called from the constructor of MainPage, the only page currently.

Note 2: Here's an error that pops up when I run it in the simulator (this error is from my regular desktop environment though (sorry for the poor quality). I'm using a Windows 7 machine I recently upgraded to Windows 8 RTM: [image: Display Driver Crash]

Note 3: The Windows built in Camera app works fine.

Comment: Are you using the latest version (RTM) or any of the Previews?

Comment: Have you stepped through to see which line is causing the crash?

Comment: It's kind of strange, because no actual errors are thrown, but I think it's the `InitializeAsync` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out it was a silly mistake by myself. Hopefully if anyone else is doing the same thing though they can find this. What happened apparently is that when I closed the app, VS 2012 continued debugging. When I reopened the app (from the start menu) VS was still debugging the last run. This somehow led to the display driver crashing. If anyone wants to explain in more depth why this would happen, I'd be glad. I'll mark this as the correct answer after I'm certain that this was causing all the display driver crashes.

Answer (score 0):

By the message i guess, the problem is in your graphic card drivers, if you're using the default/included ones, try using some more specific (like the ones you can get at Nvidia or ATI websites) if you're using the drivers provided by the manufacturer of your card, then try the default/generic ones. A good option could be debbuging your application inside the Simulator instead of the real machine or (if you can) use a virtual machine.

Comment: Interestingly, I have the same behavior on the simulator. The first run in the simulator works, but if you close the app and open it again, the display driver crashes. I added the error message it shows then up top.

Comment: Just an FYI... the "simulator" is actually an RDP session back into your own desktop so it will be using the same drivers, system settings, etc. as your "main" desktop.